# Untangle Django (How should I start going at a lot of legacy code of several years with django that started in 0.97)

Tags: python, django

So herein lies my question.

Django project that was originally developed several years ago when django was still 0.97 version. The code was continuously built on to the point where I think band aids upon bandaids on top of bandaids is not going to cut it.

How can I start with untangling this django project?

Currently the project is in 1.2.7
Python being used is 2.6

The main thing I want to find out is what have been the most common traps that people fell into when developing a django project.

*The unit tests are most definitely one place to catch problems, but I was thinking of something more general. For example several pages take a very long time to load, if anyone had similar problems what were their solutions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would personally start with a solid set of UnitTests. Once you have your test suite, you can create a second project based on 1.4 (which is coming out imminently) and run the tests looking for failures.

docs are here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/testing/

Correct the failures or remove the offending code in favor of something that is 1.4 compliant.

From there, you might want to go back and refactor the codebase to reflect the changes that django has made. Specifically, I would go back and look to see what has changed:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/releases/

I would consider removing anything that django has since implemented. Run the tests again.

You might want to take this opportunity to shift to python2.7, if you aren't already there.

Comment: apologies for poorly phrased question, I will be updating it in a second. My main concern is untangling the code itself rather then migrating (currently it is at 1.2.7). Reason why I mentioned the original version it was developed was because there might have been significant changes that may help the tangle.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably a place where lots and lots of tests will help you. It's not my project, but here's what I'd probably do:

- Start a completely new project in Django 1.4
- Write front-end tests for the current application
- Write a script to migrate the database from 0.93 to 1.4 (it sounds like you have lots of special cases, with your patches, so I hold no hope for anything automated)
- Write lots of unit tests for the 1.4 application.

Take it module by module, and eventually you'll have everything updated.

I know it sounds like a lot of work, but it will save you time in the long run. Also, the expertise on 0.93 is slowly dying as we move further and further away from it, so you're better off staying current. That way, you can take advantage of all the new techniques for performance and such that are coming out today.